# How to match string with regexp and conditionally do stuff with capture groups

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, perl

The idea here is to change remotes from http to ssh in all git repositories

```
find / -type d -name '.git' 2>/dev/null | xargs -I {} $SHELL -c \
'cd $(dirname {}) && echo $(pwd) > /tmp/log.log && git remote | \
perl -ne "if (`git config --get remote.$_.url` =~ m#https://(.*)/(username.*)#){`git remote remove $_ && git remote add $_ git\@$1:$2`}"
```

What I want to do is to find all my (hense username in perl regex) repositories and switch them to use ssh instead of http. I've tested perl script, it's working properly, but when I use it in command it outputs this

`fatal: No such remote: remote
syntax error at -e line 1, near "( =~"
syntax error at -e line 1, near ";}"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
xargs: /bin/zsh: exited with status 255; aborting`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want (what the exact expected command is), but this:

```
printf "%s\n" 'https://github.com/username/reponame.git' \
 'git@github.com:username/reponame' | perl -lne \
'if (m#https://(.*?)/(.*/)#) {print "git remote remove $_ && git remote add $_ git\@$1:$2"}'
```

should print

```
git remote remove https://github.com/username/reponame.git && git remote add https://github.com/username/reponame.git git@github.com:username/
```

(Change the `print` to `system` if you're sure you want to run the commands)

---

I changed the `for r in xyz` to input the URL:s to Perl's stdin, if you want to give them on the command line, you could do something like

```
perl -le '$_=shift; if (m#http://(.*?)/(.*/)#) {print "blah $_ $1:$2"}' http://foo.bar/user/something
```

to drop the command line argument to `$_` (which is implicitly used by `m//` unless you specify something else with `$var =~ m//`).

Also, better escape the `@` in the string, as it's the sigil for an array variable.

Comment: okay, so i'm actually need `git remote | some perl code that will do the work`. I'm trying `$remote = qx(git config --get remote.$_.url);
print $remote;
}` but this isn't working